# Which loss is displayed during training of Keras nested models?

Tags: keras

I have a Keras model composed of 3 other Keras models (nested models). My question is about the meaning of the loss values displayed in the Keras training logs.

**Here is the summary of my global model:**

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_16 (InputLayer)           (None, 256, 256, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)                 (None, 16, 16, 128)  690368      input_16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_4 (Model)                 [(None, 17, 4), (None, 17, 4), (None, 16, 16, 128)] 5103826     input_16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_8 (Concatenate)     (None, 16, 16, 256)  0           model_1[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_4[1][2]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (Model)                 (None, 256, 256, 3)  582843      concatenate_8[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
```

These nested models are 2 encoders (`model_1` and `model_4`) and 1 decoder (`decoder`).

I also have 3 losses: 2 losses that are applied to 2 of the `model_4` outputs directly, and one loss that is applied to the output of the decoder.

When I train the full model, I only see for `model_4` one loss, which is called `model_4_loss`:

```
Epoch 34/60
13548/19512 [===================>..........] - ETA: 34:57 - loss: 0.6764 - decoder_loss: 0.0944 - model_4_loss: 0.2797
```

But when I tried training `model_4` alone I saw the 2 losses distinctly in the training logs (here the `concatenate_xxx` losses correspond to the `model_4` first 2 outputs):

```
Epoch 35/60
 5430/19512 [=======>......................] - ETA: 1:20:14 - loss: 0.8475 - concatenate_5_loss: 0.2998 - concatenate_7_loss: 0.2767
```

I have several questions about this:

- When training the full model, shouldn't I see 3 losses instead of 2 (2 for the `model_4` and one for `decoder`?
- What does `model_4_loss` represents? The mean of the 2 losses from `model_4`? The sum? Only one of the two?
- How can I make the training logs display the two losses of `model_4` distinctly instead of some aggregated value?

To provide more context, here is a summary of how I built the whole model:

```
encoder1 = build_encoder1()   # returns an object of type `Model` with a single (None, 16, 16, 128) output
encoder2 = build_encoder2()   # returns an object of type `Model` with a list of 3 tensors as output
decoder = build_decoder()     # returns a `Model` with a single (None, 256, 256, 3) output

inp = Input(shape=input_shape)      # input_shape is (None, 256, 256, 3)
z_1 = encoder1(inp)                 # (None, 16, 16, 128)
out1, out2, z_2 = encoder2(inp)     # [(None, 17, 4), (None, 17, 4), (None, 16, 16, 128)]

concat = concatenate[z_1, z_2]      # (None, 16, 16, 256)
out3 = decoder(concat)              # (None, 256, 256, 3)

outputs = [out3, out1, out2]
losses = [loss1(), loss2(), loss2()]     # loss1 is a custom loss function managing the (None, 256, 256, 3) output and loss2 is another managing the (None, 17, 4) outputs
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=start_lr))
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can name your models, i.e. add `name="YourName1"` as an argument in the `Model` constructor. Then, instead of providing a list of losses to the `model.compile` method, you can pass a dict there, like this:

```py
losses = {
    "YourName1": loss1(),
    "YourName2": loss2(),
    "YourName3": loss2()
}

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=start_lr))
```

NB: you can have the loss `loss2()` twice if both `YourName2` and `YourName3` models work with it.